# Decile Ranking for Time-Series in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, percentile

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the below, and I am trying to obtain the decile ranking for each column's row and then create a new column for each feature within the dataframe:

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well, but I ultimately want to produce a dataframe that looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qcut - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html

EDIT: If you want to get results relative to the row (as specified in comment below), you can use apply (and add suffix to rename the columns), for example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"a": [-0.1095, 0.1801, 0.0623, 0.1003, -0.0725],
                     "b": [-0.1895, 0.2001, 0.0523, 0.1203, -0.0225],
                     "c": [-0.0695, 0.2121, 0.1023, 0.2023, -0.0325],
                     "d": [-0.0495, 0.2401, 0.1223, 0.1603, -0.0125]},
                index = ["11/30/1984", "12/31/1984", "1/31/1985", "2/26/1985", "3/31/1985"])

test2 = test.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, duplicates='drop', labels = False), axis=1)\
            .add_suffix('_decile_row')

pd.concat([test, test_2], axis=1)
```

Which will produce:

```
            a       b       c       d       a_decile_row    b_decile_row    c_decile_row    d_decile_row
11/30/1984  -0.110  -0.190  -0.070  -0.050  3               0               6               9
12/31/1984  0.180   0.200   0.212   0.240   0               3               6               9
1/31/1985   0.062   0.052   0.102   0.122   3               0               6               9
2/26/1985   0.100   0.120   0.202   0.160   0               3               9               6
3/31/1985   -0.072  -0.022  -0.033  -0.013  0               6               3               9
```

Comment: So i think with this solution, pd.qcut will give me the decile ranking for that specific data point relative to all of the other data points in that same column. I am looking for the decile ranking for a, b, c, d at the specific date in time, so relative to each unique column, rather than relative to the same column

Comment: OK, my bad. I didn't understand the question then. But you can still use this function, just with extra shennanigans. I edited my answer